# Installing Ubuntu from External HD

Tags: usb, hard-drive

I have a laptop that doesn't seem to detect the DVD of the iso I burned it to. Oddly enough, it does detect any other dvd or cd.

I would like to do a full install to this laptop but I only have an External Hard Drive (USB).

Is there a way I can install Ubuntu from a USB External Hard Drive?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is.
You can download an Ubuntu iso from [Ubuntu's official Website](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/)

Then, you can make a live USB with [UNetBootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/) which is a tool for creating bootable live USB drives.

Here is a screenshot of UNetBootin:

[image]