# How to install Ubuntu from an external HDD?

Tags: system-installation, external-hdd

I already saw that there is an old thread ([Installing Ubuntu from External HD](https://askubuntu.com/questions/544703/installing-ubuntu-from-external-hd)) from 2014 on this but wanted to make to sure if there is any new trick or workaround for this problem

I have a Windows OS running on my laptop and I want to install Ubuntu alongside it. I don't have a USB pen drive but I have a External HDD of 2 TB size

Comment: You can use any media your machine (BIOS/uEFI) will recognize as a boot device. On a thinkpad with dead USB ports, I added replacement USB ports via expansion port; however I can't boot from that as the BIOS doesn't provide support for it.  It'll depend on what devices your hardware can boot from.  You can use hdd/sdd/thumb-drive/cd/dvd/SD-flash-memory/compact-flash or any device your hardware allows booting from (inc. *magnetic tape if it allowed for it; good luck finding a box that allows for that today though*)

Comment: Boot your system using whatever means it has that pulls up the selector of what device to boot from (that varies on device, be it F9, F12 or other key, eg. on one laptop it's a key held down whilst off that causes the device to turn on & question asked; it can't be pressed whilst laptop is on, ie. key is device specific), then it'll boot from that device (if firmware settings are setup to allow for it, plus hardware allows for it).

Comment: Careful, most tools to create installer assume you have a smaller flash drive and totally erase it. The tools that use dd erase the first 2+GB for the image as a hybrid DVD/flash drive. That overwrites partition table and in effect erases entire drive as it cannot be seen. Better to spend the few bucks to just get a flash drive. Also you should have both the Ubuntu live installer and a Windows repair/recovery flash drive to make repairs, anyway. Or get two flash drives.

Comment: The link you posted should work well. UNetbootin will install a Live Linux installer without formatting the external drive. UNetbootin only installs to a FAT32 partition. If the USB external drive is formatted as NTFS, you can make a temporary 4GB FAT32 partition and install Ubuntu to that. As oldfred said, there are not many other Linux installers that do not completely overwrite the USB drive.

Comment: @StanGeo: With apologies to pendrivelinux.com, I should mention that YUMI 2.0.7.9, (BIOS version, not 0.0.3.1 UEFI version) and Universal USB Installer 1.9.9.7 will both install Live Linux to NTFS partitions without overwriting the whole partition. They will overwrite any MBR's on the partition with a Syslinux MBR, but it is very unlikely there is already an MBR on it unless it has an OS already installed.

Answer (score 0):

### Installing Ubuntu from External USB Drive

Ubuntu can be installed from an external USB drive.

There are a few Challenges: Many Live installers such as Etcher, dd, mkusb, Gnome-Disks, Startup Disk Creator, Ventoy, Win32DiskImager, etc, clone the ISO as a ISO9660 partition and overwrite everything on the disk.

Other Live installers such as UNetbootin and YUMI-BIOS/UEFI, (version 0.0.8.1) will install to a partition on the disk, but only to a FAT32 partition They will not overwrite the whole disk like ISO9660 installers will. The maximum size of a FAT32 partition is 32GB on Windows, so most larger drives come as NTFS. A 4GB partition can be created on an external USB drive and Ubuntu Live can be installed to it.

YUMI-BIOS only, (version 2.0.7.9) and Universal USB installer, (version 1.9.9.7), will install to a NTFS partition without overwriting the whole disk or partition. These tools are available free from Pendrivelinux.com.

All of the above installers will overwrite any MBR on the partition being installed to, so we should be careful not to try to install Ubuntu or, any Linux, to a partition with a useful OS on it.